# I can't run a simple Grails functional test using Geb and spock

Tags: grails, functional-testing, spock, geb, grails-2.0

I'm asking for help because I don't know what to do with this error...
So first of all let me show the stacktrace I get when running my really simple test, what is weird is that my test doesn't seem to be executed ...  ? 
I'm using Grails 2.0

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/
| Running 3 functional tests... 1 of 0
| Failure:  initializationError(SecondaryTest)
|  java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:166)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
| Running 3 functional tests... 2 of 0
| Failure:  initializationError(SecondaryTest)
|  java.lang.Exception: The @Rule '_gebReportingSpecTestName' must be public.

    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.addError(RuleFieldValidator.java:90)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validatePublic(RuleFieldValidator.java:67)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validateField(RuleFieldValidator.java:55)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validate(RuleFieldValidator.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateFields(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:170)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
| Running 3 functional tests... 3 of 0
| Failure:  initializationError(SecondaryTest)
|  java.lang.Exception: The @Rule '_gebReportingSpecTestName' must implement MethodRule or TestRule.
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.addError(RuleFieldValidator.java:90)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validateTestRuleOrMethodRule(RuleFieldValidator.java:73)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validateField(RuleFieldValidator.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validate(RuleFieldValidator.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateFields(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:170)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
| Completed 3 functional tests, 3 failed in 40ms
| Server stopped
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in target/test-reports
```

And here the groovy files :

SecondaryTest.groovy :

```
import pages.SignInPage
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

class SecondaryTest extends GebReportingSpec {

    String getBaseUrl() { "http://localhost:8080/" }

    File getReportDir() { new File("target/reports/geb") }

    def "I am at siginin page"() {
        when:
        to SignInPage

        then:
        true
    }
}
```

SignInPage.groovy :

```
package pages

import geb.Page

class SignInPage extends Page {

    static url = "login/auth"

    static at = { title == "Sign in" }

    static content = {
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test classes must end in `Spec` not `Test`. Otherwise Grails won't recognize them as Spock specifications.

Comment: yes ! Thanks !!
the solution was SO obvious I couldn't see it :-)

Comment: Does that mean all my previous unit tests have to be renamed to somethingSpec?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "my previous unit tests". *Spock test classes* have to end in `Spec`. Note that this question is specific to Grails.